# How to explain “treatments” in this sentence？

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

"The organization said it shipped 600,000 treatments of the Oxford―AstraZeneca vaccine to the African country."

Comment: Treatment = dose.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost certainly the case, as @Michael Harvey commented, that "treatment" simply means "dose" in this context.

However, given the specific topic, of a two-dose COVID-related vaccine, then I suppose it's possible that "treatment" could be referring to *double* doses. That is, 600,000 treatments would be equivalent to 1,200,000 doses. But that is extremely unlikely, given the way these words are typically used.

Answer (score -1):

The sentence is incorrect. A treatment in medical terminology is something which is given to people who already have a disease or other condition. Vaccines by contrast are given to people who do not currently have the condition to protect them and others in future. As Michael Harvey mentioned in a comment the appropriate phrase here is 600000 doses.

For instance the [Wikipedia page on vaccination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaccination) mentions dose six times but treatment not at all. The [Our World in Data](https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus) page on coronavirus has two mentions of dose but none of treatment. The British Broadcasting Corporation evening news calls them doses and jabs although jab is an informal use.

Comment: I suppose that such a technical distinction might apply in some formal textbook context, but it's not the case in general usage.